# RSelenium with RSDriver. Error: httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused

Tags: r, docker, web-scraping, windows-7, rselenium

I am trying to use `RSelenium` for webscraping. I am following the basics tutorial as explained on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html). The recommended approach is to install Docker (see tutorial as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused) stackoverflow answer). If I understand correctly, this is not an option for me as I am operating on Windows 7 for which `Docker` seems not to be available (see [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-stable-installer-not-running-windows-7/38622/2)).

Thus, I am trying option 2 using the RSDriver. I run

```
RSelenium::rsDriver()

remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)
    
remDr$open()
```

and get the error

```
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
```

This question has been asked and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028200/rselenium-connection-refused-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880700/error-in-checkerrorres-undefined-error-in-httr-call-httr-output-failed-to), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873151/how-to-resolve-rselenium-error-message-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-4444) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661942/rselenium-port-4445-connection-refused), though these are about the same error when using Docker and their solutions did not work for me.

Is there anyway to get this running with `rsDriver`? Is there any option for me as a Windows 7 user?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Late answer: No, for me the problem is still unsolved. I went with Python Selenium in the end.

Answer (score 0):

With `RSelenium` version 1.7.7 this is a workaround:

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4445L,
  browser = "firefox"
)
```

This command combines the server setup, and driver initation.

Answer (score 0):

My issue (on Mac) was updating Java:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk19-mac

Worked after this.

Comment: The question specifies being on Windows, and answers should be more than just a link

Comment: Posted a Mac solution as this question would be marked as a duplicate if asked specifically for Mac. The answer is to install the software from the link to get a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Yiou could consider the two following approaches to use RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox') # Docker has to be installed
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.my_Website.com")
```

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.my_Website.com")
```